# How to connect to laravel soketi from other client except laravel-echo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-websockets, uwebsockets

I am using laravel soketi package. And I dont want to use laravel-echo for client connection. So, I am testing with firecamp. But not able to connect.

Soketi is up and running with

```
  Server is up and running!
    The Websockets server is available at 127.0.0.1:6001
    The HTTP API server is available at http://127.0.0.1:6001
    The /usage endpoint is available on port 9601.
```

and in firecamp to connect I use url as `ws://localhost:6001/`
but it could not get connected.
[image]

So, how to get connected?

Comment: Did you come right here? Im also looking